# ggraph: Vertex position according to attribute

Tags: r, igraph, ggraph

Suppose I have an `igraph` graph like the following:

```r
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)

vertices <- data.frame(name = LETTERS[1:6],
                       time = c(0, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10))
edges <- data.frame(from = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C"),
                    to =   c("B", "D", "E", "C", "E", "F"))
graph <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, 
                               directed = TRUE, 
                               vertices = vertices)
```

For present purposes, the graph will always be a tree or a DAG, and I would like to use `ggraph` to plot the graph in a tree-like layout. My question is: **How to plot this graph with the `time` vertex attribute for y-values**?

I can set `aes(y = time)` in `geom_node_point` to correctly position the nodes, but the edges do not follow along:

```r
ggraph(graph, layout = "tree") + 
  geom_node_point(aes(y = time)) +
  geom_edge_link() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Setting the `y` or `yend` aesthetic to `time` in `geom_edge_link` throws an error.

I am new to `ggraph`, so I'm stuck on how to proceed with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not pretty, but you can achieve this by creating your own layout.

```
LO = layout_as_tree(graph)
LO[, 2] = V(graph)$time

ggraph(graph, layout = LO) + 
  geom_node_point() +
  geom_edge_link() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: graph with time as y-axis in layout]

Comment: Thank you! Note that doing it this way, it appears `aes(y = time)` is superfluous. I'll leave the question open for a bit in the hopes that it's possible to do it a bit cleaner, otherwise I'll accept this. (+1)